how signature is calculated in the karate framework and how to handle it?
I am sorry in advance because I cannot share code snippets due to company policy. I am facing an issue with Signature. I searched online but could not find a resolution for my issue. I have a post request with a signature in the header. In the response, I get signatureDoesNotMatch. Is there a way to print what signature is generated in the karate framework?
I tried the print method and found a signature-related question in Stackoverflow that did not solve my problem.

sorry, the link has all the information available - especially this link: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1385 - if that does not help you may need to look for other options
